# I created a encryption key-pair in Enigmail, but I can't see it when I do `gpg --list-keys` in terminal

Tags: gpg, enigmail

I installed the Enigmail mail encryption plugin for Thunderbird and created a key-pair as the installation wizard instructed me. I can send and encrypt/decrypt mail with this key.

However, when I want to list my keys in the terminal using `gpg --list-keys` I get no output what so ever.
Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enigmail's plugin separates itself from the standard `gpg` keyring.

That's why you don't see any output.

If you for any reason want to have your public (and private) key stored also in the `gpg` keyring, just do the following, supposing you have your public and possibly even private key stored in one file named MyNewKey.asc:

```
gpg --import MyNewKey.asc
```

Example output of adding the private key to the gpg keyring:

```
gpg: key E46008C3: secret key imported
gpg: key E46008C3: "Vlastimil Burián <info@vlastimilburian.cz>" not changed
gpg: key E46008C3: "Vlastimil Burián <info@vlastimilburian.cz>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 2
gpg:              unchanged: 2
gpg:       secret keys read: 1
gpg:   secret keys imported: 1
```

---

If you don't know how to get the keys from inside Enigmail to a file:

Thunderbird menu (<kbd>F10</kbd>) -> Enigmail -> Key Management -> select your key -> right click -> Export Keys to File -> Export Secret Keys.

[image: secret key]

Comment: Thanks for writing this informative answer! So where (in folder structure) does Enigmail store it's keys?